# SocketRocket scan network and connect

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, websocket, socketrocket

I'm new to SocketRocket and what I want to do is to scan the network 192.168.1.x and when it finds the server connect to it.
this is my code:

```
NSString *seg=@"ws://192.168.1.";
    NSString *puerto=@":5000";
    self.socketReady = NO;
    for (int i=0; i<255; i++) {
        NSMutableString *ip =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [ip appendString:seg];
        [ip appendString:[@(i) stringValue]];
        [ip appendString:puerto];
        self.serverSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:ip]];
        self.serverSocket.delegate = self;
        [self.serverSocket open];

    }
```

I know that [self.serverSocket open] can only be done once, but I don't know how to scan and then connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.serverSocket open]` is an asynchronous call - that is, it will immediately return, with your delegate method `webSocketDidOpen:` being called when/if the socket successfully connects or `didFailWithError:` if it doesn't.

You *could* change you loop so that it used a local variable rather than your property -

```
NSString *seg=@"ws://192.168.1.";
int puerto=5000;

for (int i=0; i<255; i++) {
    NSString *ip =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d:%d",seg,i,puerto];

    SRWebSocket *newSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:ip]];
    newSocket.delegate = self;
    [newSocket open];

}
```

and then in the delegate method you would need to store the socket that connected successfully -

```
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket
  {
     self.serverSocket=webSocket;
     //TO DO start processing data on the socket...
  }
```

*BUT* this is a pretty ugly way of locating and connecting to a service:

- It 'spams' the local network with multiple connection requests
- It wastes a considerable amount of resources on your local device
- It doesn't handle the case where there are multiple services/servers running on your port on different devices
- What if the local network isn't 192.168.1.x ?

You should investigate other options for identifying your servers address such as Bonjour or even a simple application preference to set the server address